# How to fix error 'Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable' in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I know this error has been answered before, but I am following a guide to create my first sql database with MAMP, and received this error when opening the database. Could anyone help me troubleshoot this please? I'm sure it's very simple but I followed the guide exactly and can't find any typos or errors.

Is it possible the error has to do with the way I set-up the database or could it be something I did in Unity? I assume the 615 refers to a line of code or an error number? What would be the way to troubleshoot this in the future or to know where the error is?

The guide I followed had me create the script in Sublime Text and save it locally then access it with MAMP. I'm used to coding in C++ and more recently C# so these are hieroglyphics to me.

```
Warning in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#615
 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

.\libraries\sql.lib.php#2128: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#2079: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'unityaccess',
string 'players',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `players`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
.\sql.php#219: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'unityaccess',
string 'players',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `players`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

This is the code that led to the error message.

```
<?php

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'unityaccess');

//check that connection happened
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "1: Connection failed"; //error code #1 = connection failed
    exit();
}

$username = $_POST ["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];

//check if name exists
$namecheckquery = "SELECT username FROM players WHERE username='" . $username . "'";

$namecheck = mysqli_query($con, $namecheckquery) or die("2: Name check query failed"); //error code #2 - name check query failed

if (mysqli_num_rows($namecheck) > 0)
{
    echo "3: Name already exists"; //error code #3 - name exists cannot register
    echo();
}

//add user to the table
$salt = "\$5\$rounds=5000\$" . "steamedhams" . $username . "\$";
$hash = crypt($password, $salt);
$insertuserquery = "INSERT INTO players (username, hash, salt) VALUES ('" . $username . "', '" . $hash . "', '" . $salt . "');";
mysqli_query($con, $insertuserquery) or die("4: Insert player query failed"); //error code #4 - insert query failed

echo ("0");



?>
```

Comment: What's the error message? If you think Unity is part of the problem, where's your Unity code?

Comment: I recently solved this, and I would consider this question as a duplicate, but since you already are aware of that, I will suppose that nothing worked for you. I will have to ask you to literally go to this file: `.\libraries\sql.lib.php` and look for the error on line 615. You'll find that `count()` is not closed correctly, causing a `boolean` to be passed instead of the array/object. Use your own instinct to solve it. Namely, add parentheses where necessary. Also, restart Apache after doing that.

Comment: Thank you Zeke, it looks like you are correct but again being that I've never touched php/sql before, I don't know the correct syntax. I've never edited the sql.lib.php file, but I set-up the database through MAMP/PHPMyAdmin. This is the code on line 615.            || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)     When I close the parenthesis at the end of the expression, or after the brackets, I get internal server error 500 when trying to access it from PHP MyAdmin. I've also tried adding ; to the end of the line.

Comment: You don't only have to add a closing parenthesis, but also an opening one: `|| ((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)`. That should work.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to answer, you did not mention me so I did not get a notification.

Comment: @Zeke you should make this an answer instead of a comment, and JohnZ12 should accept it because this was the correct answer.

Comment: @CasperWilkes sure thing, I never did because JohnZ12 never actually confirmed it was, but I'm pretty sure that was the correct answer too. I'll go ahead and do it.

Answer (score 5):

1. Go to this file: `.\libraries\sql.lib.php`
2. Look for the error on line 615. You'll find that `count()` is not closed correctly, causing a `boolean` to be passed instead of the `array/object`.
3. Replace the entire line 615 with this: `|| ((count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)`.

That should work.

## Aug 2020 update

See `Stuart Clark`'s answer for a newer solution applicable to PHP 7.2.24 using Ubuntu 18.04LTS and probably a newer version of phpMyAdmin. Upvote his answer if that solution helped you.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. All others mentioned on this page gave me "500 Internal Server Error".

Answer (score 3):

This answer applies to PHP 7.2.24 (using Ubuntu 18.04LTS), similar to Zeke's answer:

1. Edit: /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php
2. Closing bracket is in the wrong place on line # 613

```
    || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
```

```
change to
```

```
    || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1
```

3. Save the file

Comment: I still can't believe this has not been fixed yet

Answer (score 1):

I had still issues with all above approaches under Ubuntu 18.04 (in end of year 2021, could not believe it)

my solution was to replace existing with following code

```
function PMA_isRememberSortingOrder($analyzed_sql_results)
{
    return $GLOBALS['cfg']['RememberSorting']
        && ! ($analyzed_sql_results['is_count']
            || $analyzed_sql_results['is_export']
            || $analyzed_sql_results['is_func']
            || $analyzed_sql_results['is_analyse'])
        && $analyzed_sql_results['select_from']
        && ((empty($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']))
            || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
                && ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))
        && count($analyzed_sql_results['select_tables']) == 1;
}
```

basically I fixed

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)
```

to

```
|| (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1)
```

and

```
&& ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*')))
```

to

```
&& ($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'][0] == '*'))
```